# Add AUC as loss function for keras

Tags: theano, keras

Has anyone had any luck with writing a custom AUC loss function for Keras using Theano?

The documentation is here: http://keras.io/objectives/

Sample code is here: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/objectives.py

I saw there is an implementation in pylearn2, (which is really a wrapper around sklearn) but was unable to port this to use in Keras

https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/train_extensions/roc_auc.py

So i guess my question is, has anybody been able to write this function? and would you be willing to share?

Comment: You can easily wrap the RocAUCOp defined in the pylearn2 library.  In keeping with keras signatures, it would look something like (untested) `def roc_auc(y_true, y_hat): return RocAucScoreOp()(y_true, y_hat)`

Comment: I tried implementing their suggestion of wrapping [the RocAucScoreOp from pylearn2.](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/train_extensions/roc_auc.py) When attempting to pass this as the loss function to model.compile I got the following error: > AttributeError: 'RocAucScoreOp' object has no attribute 'grad' The source code documentation around RocAucScoreOp in pylearn2 suggests it is only intended to be used on the monitoring channel, rather than as the objective/loss function for optimization. It seems that unless there is a way to define a gradient, Keras can't use it a

Comment: The pylearn2 version is basically a callback to calculate AUC. You won't be able to use AUC as a network's modeling objective (in Keras or elsewhere) because it's not differentiable.

Answer (score 8):

AUC is not differentiable, so you can't use it as a loss function without some modification.  There's been [some work](http://www.icml-2011.org/papers/198_icmlpaper.pdf) on algorithms to maximize AUC, but I'd recommend just using the regular cross-entropy / log likelihood loss.